# Notification model in angular programming

Tags: angularjs, mongoose, notifications

I'm developing an admin panel using AngularJS with [Neon theme](http://demo.neontheme.com/dashboard/main/)

Notification model in db looks like that:

```
mongoose.model('Notification', {
projectId :  {type: String},
fromUserId: {type:String},
toUserId: {type:String},
title :  {type: String},
text :  {type: String},
isRead:  {type: Boolean, default:false},
sendDate:  {type: Date},
readDate:  {type: Date}
});
```

What is the best way to implement it ?

Should I pull all notifications for user at log and keep it in the localStorage as the other user details, or should I keep it a the scope\session\cookie ?

Comment: Why are your `projectId`, `fromUserId`, `toUserId` strings? Wouldn't it be better to use have them as `ObjectId` with a `ref`?
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: Doesn't it takes too much space ?

Comment: Too much space in the sense?

Comment: In the hard drive - in the db. More processing time.

Comment: No. `ObjectId` in the sense, it just stores the `_id` value. Not the whole `object`

Comment: Ok, I'll fix it. Thanks, except it, the logic seems ok ?

Comment: What logic are you talking about?

Comment: Keeping whole notifications data in localStorage

Comment: That works. It all boils down to how your application layer logic is. But remember, there is a limit on the amount of data you can store in `localStorage` in many browsers.